# How to edit binary file in Android?

Tags: java, android, arrays, file, binary

I want to create an app that can open binary file, read and edit it's content in decimal values, and then save it back to binary file.

This file that I want to open have multiple parameters written in 2 bytes. e.g. `00 06 00 50 01 AB = 6, 80, 427`
So far I managed to open bin file, put all data from file into `byte[]`.

Here is the code to open and read file:

```
String path = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
File file = new File(path + "/file.bin");
int size = (int) file.length();
byte[] bytes = new byte[size];

FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
try {
    fis.read(bytes);
    ...
} finally {
    fis.close();
}
```

Here is first attempt to convert `byte[]` into deciaml values:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size / 2; i = i + 2) {
    intArray[i] = ((bytes[i] & 0xff) << 8) | (bytes[i + 1] & 0xff);
}
```

But in this code only every second value is correct. It's shows `6,0,80,0,1` and should be `6,80,1`.

The second idea was to convert `byte[]` into `String[]` and then into e.g. `int[]` but It doesn't work as intended. In this fragment I didn't parse whole array, but only `hexArray[4]` which was `50` in hex and `80` in dec, but the result was `50`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i = i + 2) {
    num1 = String.format("%02X", bytes[i] & 0xFF);
    num2 = String.format("%02X", bytes[i + 1] & 0xFF);

    String twoByte = num1 + num2;
    hexArrayWithNull[i] = twoByte;
}
String[] hexArray = Arrays.stream(hexArrayWithNull).filter(Objects::nonNull).toArray(String[]::new);
num = String.format("%d", Integer.parseInt(hexArray[4]));
```

I'm quite stuck here and need some guidance. I must say also that I'm new in programming.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You increment `i` in each iteration by 2 and you store in `intArray[i]`. So, you store in index [0] then index [2] then index [4] and so on. This explains the zeros at odd indices [1], [3], ...

Also, you must continue the loop until `size`, not `size/2`.

Here is the correct loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i = i + 2) {
    intArray[i/2] = ((bytes[i] & 0xff) << 8) | (bytes[i + 1] & 0xff);
}
```

Here is the another possibility:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size/2; i = i + 1) {
    intArray[i] = ((bytes[2*i] & 0xff) << 8) | (bytes[2*i + 1] & 0xff);
}
```

[EDIT]

The reverse operation would be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size/2; i = i + 1) {
    bytes[2*i] = (intArray[i] & 0xff00) / 256; //or >>8 instead of /256
    bytes[2*i+1] = intArray[i] & 0xff;
}
```

Comment: The `intArray[i/2]` works perfect. Thanks. Now it's just how to reverse it and writte it back to binary file.

Comment: If the solution is good, thank you for voting up and marking the answer as "the solution".